How come the input of deep Q-learning differs between training and usage?
I know that in training, we need to input s,a,r,s' into the network to train. But, after the training, we only need to input s. I dont quite understand this. Actually the output also changes. In training, we input s,a,r,s', the output is y. But after trainig, we input s, the output is several values for different actions.
It is quite different with supervised learning, if we input a,b,c, and use it to update y in training. After the model is trained, we also need to input a b c to get the predicted y.  If we only input a, its not possible to get the y.
But in DQN, How come the input of deep Q-learning differs between training and usage?
I expect an answer. Thanks.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
